# Java Statement Object Reuse?

Tags: java, jdbc

I would like to know if we can reuse the same Statement object for executing more than one query. Or, should we create a new statement for different queries.

For example,

```
Connection con = getDBConnection();
Statement st1 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
int i = st1.executeUpdate("update tbl_domu set domU_status=1 where domU_id=" + dom_U_id);
Statement st2 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
int j = st2.executeUpdate("insert into tbl_domU_action_history values('" + dom_U_name + "', 1, '" + date + "')");
```

In the above case, is there any harm in using the same statement st1 for both the executeUpdate() queries? Can I use the same Statement object st1 for another executeQuery()?

Answer (score 23):

I came across the response I was looking for in the Javadoc for [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one `ResultSet` object per `Statement` object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one `ResultSet` object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different `Statement` objects. All execution methods in the `Statement` interface implicitly close a current `ResultSet` object of the statement if an open one exists.

Comment: It don't see how this answers the question : should we call the close() method on the Statement ?

Comment: @PhilippeGirolami The Question is about reusing a `Statement` object, not about closing. So this Answer directly addresses the Question, with Javadoc explaining that a `Statement` can indeed be used again to produce another `ResultSet` but only one `ResultSet` at a time is usable.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can. However, it is very much better to use `PreparedStatement` to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

The original point of using prepared statements was to avoid having the database parse and recompile the statement, so it's supposed to be faster.

I had not considered the SQL injection vulnerabilities use, but I'm not sure what, if any data checking is done. I suspect that it's driver-dependant, as the driver implementation is free to just glue the statements together. If anyone has further details, please post.

Comment: It appears that the JDBC spec does not require correct handling of special characters. I'd like to hear about any drivers that do not so they can be avoided.

Comment: Steve, the idea re: SQL injection is that using parameterized statements avoids the risk.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Preventing_SQL_Injection.  Of course you are right that their original purpose was to avoid unnecessary parsing.

Comment: Yes, however as the drivers merely implement the JDBC interface(s) it's unclear to what extent this is actually happening, and it's totally dependent on the driver implementors. I was hoping someone would have more specific knowledge based on having had to deal with this issue in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that the result sets get garbage collected if only they are only closed.  I think I had a cool memory leak when I was writing a connection pool so the same statement/connection was re-used a million times.  Kept bringing down my JVM.  I guess this could also be implementation specific as garabage collection of a closed result set may not be tested.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you assign something to a reference type, you're replacing the old reference with a new one.

For example...

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject("foo");
obj = new MyObject("bar");
```

Would have a now non-referenced instance of MyObject with some property set to "foo" that will eventually be garbage collected.

obj stores a reference to a MyObject with some property set to "bar".

Comment: This is not quite what he is doing. He is asking if he can reuse the *same* instance, not just the same reference