# JDBC Sql exhausted ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset, getstring

I have been struggling with this and I cant seem to find a fix.

```
public static void doQ(Connection c){
    try
    {
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM VQ1");
        ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM VQ2");
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs2.getMetaData();
        System.out.println(""); 
        System.out.println("Statistics for " + rs1.getString(2) + " By Spencer"); // This line recieves the error
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Orders");
        System.out.println("============================================================ =========================");
        System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %11s %12s\n", meta.getColumnName(1), meta.getColumnName(2), meta.getColumnName(3), meta.getColumnName(4));
        System.out.println("");
        while(rs2.next()){
            System.out.printf("%10s %10s %11s %12s\n",rs2.getString(1), rs2.getString(2), rs2.getString(3), rs2.getString(4));
        }//end while
        rs2.close();
        rs1.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex){
        System.err.println("\nERROR :" + ex.getMessage());

    }// end try catch

}//end method
```

I receive an exhausted resultSet error whenever I try to run my code. It should print out a full table of all the columns which works fine. the only issue i am having is with the like

```
System.out.println("Statistics for " + rs1.getString(2) + " By Spencer");
```

I have tried placing this line of code into an if(rs1.next()) but the condition is never true so it just skips the line completely. I'm completely stumped and would love some help.

My Sql Views

```
    DROP VIEW VQ1;

    CREATE VIEW VQ1
    AS
    SELECT COMPANYNAME, TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS "date"
    FROM CUSTOMERS
    GROUP BY COMPANYNAME
    WITH READ ONLY;

    DROP VIEW VQ2;

    CREATE VIEW VQ2
    AS
    SELECT O.ORDERID, TO_CHAR(O.ORDERDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS "Order date",
    NVL2(O.SHIPPEDDATE, 'Shipped', 'Not Shipped') AS "Status",
    TO_CHAR(((OD.UNITPRICE * OD.QUANTITY) - (OD.UNITPRICE * OD.QUANTITY * OD.DISCOUNT)), '$999.99') AS "Total"
    FROM ORDERS O INNER JOIN ORDERDETAILS OD
    ON O.ORDERID = OD.ORDERID
    GROUP BY O.ORDERID, TO_CHAR(O.ORDERDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), NVL2(O.SHIPPEDDATE,'Shipped', 'Not Shipped'), TO_CHAR(((OD.UNITPRICE * OD.QUANTITY) - (OD.UNITPRICE * OD.QUANTITY * OD.DISCOUNT)), '$999.99')
    WITH READ ONLY;
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/418827/2055998).

Comment: In my code i call two seperate resultset objects from two separate statements both from vq1 and vq2.

Comment: Nope. You don't. Both result sets are obtained from the **same** statement object, namely `stmt`.

Comment: I see now. Thanks!