# JDBC Statement Creation

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have this function to execute SQL statements over a connection. Assume that I have a valid connection.

```
public void runSQL(String sql) throws SQLException
{
    if (statement == null || statement.isClosed())
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    
    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

I am running different SQLs but using the `same statement.` I attempt to create a new statement if and only if the statement is no longer valid. Should I be creating a new statement for each execution?

Edit: A similar question to this one has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389832/java-statement-object-reuse) and it simply indicates that it is doable. This is what I use as well. But I have encountered a strange case where I had to create a new statement.

If I run the following queries over the same statement, I get SQL Exception

Query 1

```
CREATE DATABASE Test //Executes successfully
```

Query 2

```
Use Test //SQLException: No database selected
```

It works fine if I create a different statement for each query. I am using MySQL 8.0. It is like the statement created before `Create Database` statement is not aware of the new database information and cannot find the database.

Comment: (A) Do not edit your Question to fundamentally alter its meaning. (B) Sounds like you have found your own diagnosis and solution to your problem with `CREATE DATABASE`.

Comment: @BasilBourque Should I ask this question as a new one? About the create database part, no I haven't found an answer yet. I can execute `Create Database` and the database is actually created. But when I execute `Use [DB Name]`, SQLException is thrown with `No Database` message. If I call `use` with a newly created statement, it works fine. For DML statements, I had no issue using the same statement object. Is this a special case?